# How to handle Right mouse click event for a Tree view

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I would like to have an option as rename File if i select on a file of the treeview. If i right click the mouse i would like to have an option as Rename file and if i select that i would like to able to rename it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`TreeNode.BeginEdit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.beginedit.aspx) method allows you to put a node in edit mode (given that `LabelEdit = true` for the `TreeView` control).

Answer (score 1):

Add a [Context Menu Strip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984254%28VS.71%29.aspx) to the form with a 'Rename' entry and set that to be the `ContextMenuStrip` of the `TreeView`

```
this.treeView1.ContextMenuStrip = this.contextMenuStrip1;
```

Then on the 'Rename' click event do your renaming, checking first that there is a `TreeNode` selected

```
private void renameToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null)
      {
          // Do renaming
          TreeNode node = treeView1.SelectedNode;
          node.Text = "New Text";
      }
}
```

Comment: Instaed of giving some text can i prompt the user to save his own name

Comment: Yeah that was just an example, you can open a new form and get them to input it there or use @Fredrik's method above (which is a better way I think) and get them to enter it straight into the TreeNode